# Recurly.js and broken labels

Tags: recurly

I'm just getting started using Recurly.js on a new site and after replacing my input fields with the div placeholders that Recurly replaces with iframes the labels obviously don't work. I was a bit surprised that the iframes only contain the input and not also the appropriate label. I even tested out the examples (https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js-examples) and the labels in those don't work either. This seems like a pretty big accessibility/ux issue with no clear solution. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In testing the iframe code as shown in the examples works and labels are rendered on screen.

If you're still running into issues, please contact support@recurly.com with a sample of your code and the browser used in testing and we can assist.